# Is it possible to input one argument out of two in GraphQL?

Tags: kotlin, graphql, typegraphql, apollo-federation, netflix-dgs

I have a situation where in I have to input one parameter out of the given two.
Suppose the schema is

```
input fruit {
     apple: Apple
     banana: banana
}
```

Now, if user inputs apple, then he cannot input banana and vice-versa. Is this possible in GraphQL?

Comment: I would make them both optional and create / update them via a method that enforces the rules you described. In TypeGraphQL you can do this via a FieldResolver, I believe. Some ORMs, like TypeORM even have decorators like `@BeforeInsert` and `@BeforeUpdate` that you can use.

Comment: In my case I only have to take one input (either one). If user passes one input then he shouldn't be able to enter the other input. So, I cannot make them optional.

Comment: Why not? You create an `InputType` with both of them being optional. And before update/create you just validate. If both / none of them have been passed, you return a validation error. You even get to choose if you want the client to pass in `null` or leave the field out.

Answer (score 0):

Keep your current schema as defined (you have both optional right now). You can then add below code to throw error if both are added. (it is java code but does explain how to do it)

```
@DgsQuery
public String hello(@InputArgument Fruit fruit) {
   if (fruit.getApple() != null && fruit.getBanana() != null) {
      throw new DgsInvalidInputArgumentException("Only one fruit is allowed", null);
   }
}
```

You can create your custom error using GraphQLError object or throw your own exception and then write handler for it.

In any case, if you are looking schema only solution then it is not possible. GraphQL specs does not support this scenario out of the box.

Answer (score 0):

An additional option depending on your requirements is to use the @oneOf directive. This directive is in [RFC #825](https://github.com/graphql/graphql-spec/pull/825) and in currently in RFC 2 status (Draft status; RFC 3 is accepted status), and should be in the main branch relatively soon.

OneOf Input Objects are a special variant of Input Objects where the type system asserts that exactly one of the fields must be set and non-null, all others being omitted.

With this directive, your schema would look as follows:

```
input fruit @oneOf {
     apple: Apple
     banana: banana
}
```